# Android admob, configuration for live application

Tags: android

While I am testing my app I use this code

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my-device-id").build();
adElm = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
adElm.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I am planning on launching my application in a couple of weeks, so come launch do I just need to remove the

```
.addTestDevice("my-device-id")
```

part? And my adverts will be configured correctly to display actual adverts, and generate revenue?

Answer (score 0):

That part of the addTestDevice("my-test-device-id") is for testing. Let me explain it better, when you sell ads you cannot touch your own ads, you will be suspended. So if you put your device ID in the code, and if you use you phone, tablet "device" that have that code, it will show just test ads, that's great for avoid autoinflate.

of course you can also ad more than one device.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my-device-id1").addTestDevice("my-device-id2").build();
```

Comment: Yes, so when my app is launched do I need to keep that code in? What if I bought a new phone (eg I view the app on another device)?

Comment: In that case you must go to your code and add your new device. And theres no problem when you release your app, nothing will happen, except on your own device, it must appear test ads. I told you cannot click your own ads.

Comment: Okay so I will keep the code in, but other users will see real ads.